# WebAPI POST working but not adding to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have created a web API controller and am trying to post data to my database. When I test the API in POSTMAN, I get a 200 OK Result but a `false` return for body.

I have tried changing from `[FormBody]` instead but that doesn't work either.
I have added the method as a Boolean to check but I just receive false.

Here's an actual link to a published api:
[Add API](http://cis-iis2.temple.edu/Spring2019/cis3342_tug81959/WebAPI/api/Cities/AddCity) and [All data](http://cis-iis2.temple.edu/Spring2019/cis3342_tug81959/WebAPI/api/Cities/GetAll)

Here's what I've tried in POSTMAN using Body -> raw -> JSON/Application

```
{
    CityName: "Test1",
    State: "PA",
    Population: "0",
    MHouseholdIncome: "0",
    POwnerRenter: "0",
    MHomeValue: "0",
    MAge: "0",
    UnemploymentRate: "0",
    CrimeIndex: "0"
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
// POST: api/Cities/AddCity
        [HttpPost()]
        [HttpPost("AddCity")]
        public Boolean AddCity([FromBody]City city)
        {
            if (city != null)
            {
                DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
                SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();

                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.CommandText = "AddCity";

                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theCity", city.CityName);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theState", city.State);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thePopulation", city.Population);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theIncome", city.MHouseholdIncome);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theOwner", city.POwnerRenter);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theHomeValue", city.MHomeValue);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theMedianAge", city.MAge);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theUnemploymentRate", city.UnemploymentRate);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theCrime", city.CrimeIndex);

                int value = objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);

                if (value > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here's my code:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            City city = new City();

            city.CityName = txtCity.Text;
            city.State = ddStates.SelectedValue;
            city.Population = int.Parse(txtPopulation.Text);
            city.MHouseholdIncome = float.Parse(txtHouseholdIncome.Text);
            city.POwnerRenter = float.Parse(txtOwnerRenter.Text);
            city.MHomeValue = float.Parse(txtHomeValue.Text);
            city.MAge = float.Parse(txtAge.Text);
            city.UnemploymentRate = float.Parse(txtUnemploymentRate.Text);
            city.CrimeIndex = float.Parse(txtCrimeIndex.Text);

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String jsonCity = js.Serialize(city);

            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(webApiUrl + "AddCity/");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = jsonCity.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                writer.Write(jsonCity);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                String data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();

                if (data == "true")
                {
                    string msg = "The city was successfully added to the database.";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    string msg = "A problem occured while adding the city to the database. The data was not recorded.";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = "Error:" + ex.Message;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

City.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CityLibrary
{
    public class City
    {
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
        public float MHouseholdIncome { get; set; }
        public float POwnerRenter { get; set; }
        public float MHomeValue { get; set; }
        public float MAge { get; set; }
        public float UnemploymentRate { get; set; }
        public float CrimeIndex { get; set; }

        public City()
        {

        }

        public City(int id, string name, string state, int ppl, float income,
            float owner, float home, float age, float rate, float crime)
        {
            this.CityID = id;
            this.CityName = name;
            this.State = state;
            this.Population = ppl;
            this.MHouseholdIncome = income;
            this.POwnerRenter = owner;
            this.MHomeValue = home;
            this.MAge = age;
            this.UnemploymentRate = rate;
            this.CrimeIndex = crime;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the data to be added to the actual database.

Comment: Try to debug your code and add breakpoint on line => `int value = objDB.DoUpdateUsingCmdObj(objCmd);` and let me know the value inside  `value` variable.

Comment: I can't debug it that way because they are on two different asp.net projects but when i debug the actual page, my response, reader and everything else is null but my `jsonCity` is correct. @er-sho

Comment: @pyuntae Can you also post the code of `City` model class. Also, have you confirmed that data is not adding to database table by browsing the table itself?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I just posted. And yes I have confirmed. I also confirmed that my stored procedure does work.

Comment: To narrow down the issue update the controller action code like: `if(city==null) { throw new Exception("City parameter is null"); }` I suspect that the json being passed to the controller method is not deserialized into City object.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I did as you suggested but no exception is being thrown.

Comment: all you have to do is debug your code. run the api then fire a postman request at it, using whatever port your api is using. then you can see where the problem is, instead of trying to guess

Answer (score 0):

Check the objCmd for null, and if not, check the DoUpdateUsingCmdObj method

Comment: like i said it returns false